# Can the よう ending signify an imperative?

Tags: verbs

Can the よう ending be used for imperatives like て？

If so then can you show some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. The "～よう" conjugation is applied to 一段 verbs when forming the casual volitional form. Being the *casual* form, it doesn't mean "Shall we (speaker and listener) ..." so much as "We (speaker and listener) will ...".

> 食べよう
>   "We will eat."
>
> 寝よう
>   "We will sleep."

The proper imperative conjugation for 一段 verbs is of course "～ろう".

Comment: I thought the casual volitional form can also perform the cohortative function of "let's (speaker and listener) do ~".

Comment: Sure. But it's, well, less than polite about it.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but couldn't `食べようよ！` effectively be an imperative ordering multiple people to eat depending on the way it's said?

Comment: It also implies that the speaker will eat as well though.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oops, yeah of course it does. I think it could be used as an imperative, but not in the way the questioner was asking.